# Magento 2: Call customer login page in other phtml

Tags: magento2, login, phtml

Can any one tell me how to call customer login page in  magento2 Logo.phtml

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Get login page in any phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login")->setTemplate("Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Flush cache and try

Comment: please check it totally outside in page

Comment: @MonuKumar, The question is about how you call login page in logo.phtml. and this is the method to call login page in logo.phtml or any other phtml files. next you need to set design for it.

Comment: i want to call default sin in or create link in logo.phtml